# Suspend issues on Gnome 3 and Budgie but not on Mate

Tags: 20.04, gnome, suspend, power-management, mate

I've been having issues with suspend ever since Ubuntu 19.10 came out. The laptop I'm having this issue with is an HP Envy 13-ah0051wm that is currently fully updated with the latest BIOS. The suspend issue only happens when the desktop environment (either Gnome 3 (19.10 - 21.10) or Budgie (21.10)) is running. This does not happen on Mate (21.04 last tested). I can fall back to TTY and suspend all that I want without fail using `systemctl suspend`.

Since this is a suspend issue I haven't been able to get a lot of good data. When I try to gets the logs after a suspend they're corrupted due to the fact that I had to forcefully shut off the laptop due to it being stuck.

The laptop does support S3, so it's not the new issue with the laptop not supporting that. I'm just lost on new things to try to get it to work. While I like Mate, I'd really like to standardize on Gnome 3 or Budgie in my distributions as I'm getting to the point of not having as much time to tinker with my laptop as I used to.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

P.S. If there are any datapoints I can provide please let me know what they are and how to get them and they will be provided. Also if I need to put this in the bug tracker I can, but I want to make sure I have some data to put in there with it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134385/discussion-on-question-by-gage-greenhouse-suspend-issues-on-gnome-3-and-budgie-b).